# Elmah Error: The context cannot be used while the model is being created

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, elmah

I am getting occasional ELMAH errors in my project that say this.  However, the app seems to be working fine.  Is there a way to set ELMAH to ignore this particular error?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend ignoring this error as it is pointing to an incorrect use of the Entity Framework DbContext object in your project. Please some of these previous questions for details as to what may be causing this issue:

- [How can I prevent EF “The context cannot be used while the model is being created” errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099781/how-can-i-prevent-ef-the-context-cannot-be-used-while-the-model-is-being-create)
- [The context cannot be used while the model is being created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750115/the-context-cannot-be-used-while-the-model-is-being-created)