# Exception : The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string-Entityframework

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework-4.1

I have write a method for inserting some data to the db using Entity framework like below which is called as a wcf service

```
  bool status=false;
           MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext();
           var getData = dc.Register.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DeviceId == deviceId.Trim());
           if (getData != null)
           {
               status = true;
           }
           return status;
```

In local it insert successfully. But after publishing  i try to insert again.At that time i got exception **The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string** How can i resolve this error?

**Connectionstring**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataContext" connectionString="Data Source=MYNAME\SQL2008R2; Initial Catalog=MyDb; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Check inner exception details?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423278/ef-4-1-exception-the-provider-did-not-return-a-providermanifesttoken-string

Comment: Inner exception is The context cannot be used while the model is being created

Comment: i try to insert from my local application.It's workin fine.But after publishing i got this error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750115/the-context-cannot-be-used-while-the-model-is-being-created

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118562/ef-4-1-the-context-cannot-be-used-while-the-model-is-being-created-exception-d

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099781/how-can-i-prevent-ef-the-context-cannot-be-used-while-the-model-is-being-create

Comment: i already go through this link.all these are different scenarios. is there any pblm in my connectionString?

Comment: If you've already tried things that don't help, include that information in your answer.  Provide links you've already read up on and why they don't apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection string uses Integrated Security = true.

This means that the connection to the database is made using the security context of the calling process.

When you run locally you are in the security context of your user. Therefore, it works.

When you deploy to IIS, the default is that you are in the security context of the application pool, which is NETWORK SERVICE. Since NETWORK SERVICE does not have access to the database you get an error.

Comment: that's good point..Now i got the answer. I changed NETWORK SERVICE to Local System